# screenshot using googlepagespeed api

Tags: php, google-api

Below is my code to capture the screenshot of of webpage. But i get the output of the same as how in the image below. Kindly suggest on what is the mistake i am committing. Also kindly suggest the method to save this screenshot to the server?

[image]

```
<?php
 $url='https://www.google.com';
 $stratedy = 'mobile' ;
 $apiReqUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed';
 $apiKey = 'my_api_key' ;
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURL_OPTURL, $apiReqUrl.'?url='.$reqUrl.' 
 &key='.$apiKey.'&screenshot=true&strategy='.$stratedy);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 $result=curl_exec($curl);
 $data = json_decode($result, true);
 $img = str_replace(array('_','-'), array('/','+'), $data['screenshot'] 
 ['data']);
 echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$img.'">';
 ?>
```

Comment: Did you try this: [Generating Screenshots of URLs using Google's secret magic API](https://blog.praveen.science/generating-screenshots-of-urls-using-googles-secret-magic-api/)? It's my article and I have also given some example snippets.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, try using the HTML version from [Generating Screenshots of URLs using Google's secret magic API](https://blog.praveen.science/generating-screenshots-of-urls-using-googles-secret-magic-api/). All you need to do is to call the API and it's free (I guess).

**For example in PHP:**

```
<?php  

$url = "https://praveen.science/";

// Hit the Google PageSpeed Insights API.
// Catch: Your server needs to allow file_get_contents() to make this run. Or you need to use cURL.
$response = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?screenshot=true&url='.urlencode($url));

// Convert the JSON response into an array.
$googlePagespeedObject = json_decode($response, true);

// Grab the Screenshot data.
$screenshot = $googlePagespeedObject['screenshot']['data'];

// Fix url encoded base64
$screenshot = str_replace(array('_','-'), array('/','+'), $screenshot);

// Build the Data URI scheme and spit out an <img /> Tag.
echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,{$screenshot}\" alt=\"Screenshot\" />";

// Or.. base64 decode and store
file_put_contents('...', base64_decode($screenshot));
```

**Or in JavaScript:**

```js
$(function() {
  // Get the URL.
  var url = "https://praveen.science/";
  // Prepare the URL.
  url = encodeURIComponent(url);
  // Hit the Google Page Speed API.
  $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?screenshot=true&strategy=mobile&url=" + url, function(data) {
    // Get the screenshot data.
    var screenshot = data.screenshot;
    // Convert the Google's Data to Data URI scheme.
    var imageData = screenshot.data.replace(/_/g, "/").replace(/-/g, "+");
    // Build the Data URI.
    var dataURI = "data:" + screenshot.mime_type + ";base64," + imageData;
    // Set the image's source.
    $("img").attr("src", dataURI);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<h1>Hard Coded Screenshot of my Website:</h1>
<img src="//placehold.it/300x50?text=Loading+Screenshot..." alt="Screenshot" />
```

Comment: Added your PHP version, hope you don't mind, the OP wanted in PHP.. nice blog.. ✓ +1

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks... `:)` Doesn't rot. Lives till I live. `:)`

Comment: @KeerthanaA Did it work in your PC at all? When you clicked on the Run code snippet, did you see the screenshot getting generated?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Nope its not running Gives me the following error.   {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 15,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: @KeerthanaA Looks like you have `https://code.jquery.com` disallowed or something... `:/` Can you check that?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of APIs available on the internet to take screenshots. Something like https://www.purplescreenshots.com/ has example of integrating screenshots too.